# PHP 5.5.9 with direct IO n Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, serial-port

I need to talk to serial port which is connected to the NFC device.

First need to identify the port and later read the same.

I have been trying to use PHP Direct IO function with PHP 5.5.9 and ubuntu 14.04 but am getting the Error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function dio_open()
```

Code which I have used

```
<?php
$fp = dio_open('ttyUSB0', O_RDWR);
dio_tcsetattr($fp, array( 'baud' => 9600, 'bits' => 8, 'stop' => 1, 'parity' => 0));
if ( !$fp) {
 echo " Port not opened.";
} else {
 $string="A";
 dio_write($fp,$string);
 $result=dio_read($fp,1);
 echo $result;
 dio_close ($fp);
};
?>
```

Any help with respect to respect to PHP direct IO or any sample program link will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

according to php it is not possible to use direct IO in linux. only it can use in windows platform

reference : http://php.net/manual/en/intro.dio.php

that's why you are getting..
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function dio_open()